# Read_csv ignoring delimeters

Tags: r, csv, import

i have a problem handling a questionnaire which i need to import into R. The problem is that the following entry contains commas.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64;" x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36",Windows 8,Chrome
```

When i specify that commas should be used as delimeters is splices the entry at `"KHTML, like Gecko"` and `"...36" ,Windows 8"`. But it somehow does not split at other commas such as `"4,21 Jul 2020 - 16:06:04 CEST,21 Jul 2020 - 16:20:55 CEST,0h 14m 51s,"`

I do not understand why these cases are handled differently and how to resolve the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
4,21 Jul 2020 - 16:06:04 CEST,21 Jul 2020 - 16:20:55 CEST,0h 14m 51s,0h 57m 2s,1595340364,1595341255,5,5,,Terminating,1,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ( like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36",Windows 8,Chrome 73.0.3683.75,1920,,DKJK1995,1,1,1,4,2,2,6,6,7,1,2,5,5,4,4,2,2,3,2,2,3,4,3,3,5,5,5,2,2,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,1,2,3,3,4,3,5,6,6,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,2,3,2,3,5,5,5,6,2,2,1,2,3,5,5,4,5,2,2,3,100,0,100,0,20,72,100,0,100,0,0,0,100,0,100,0,4,5,5,4,4,4,3,3,2,4,4,5,5,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,5,2,2,3,3,5,3,3,5,5,2,2,2,2,4,3,3,4,5,2,3,2,3,5,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,24,1,2,90,60,90,6,Deutschland,4,1,2,2,1,,1,1,"1,6,5,8,3,2,7,4","6,5,7,3,1,8,4,2","2,1","1,2,4,3",3,56,92,70,54,25,64,29,132,22,34,27,136,15,66,32,109,16,46,36,132,13,31,20,132,10,40,20,107,8,25,16,84,12,27,19,91,7,148,329,355,233,185,29,216,72,"4,2,6,7,5,1,8,3","2,3,1,7,4,8,6,5","5,6,7,1,3,8,4,2","8,3,11,13,10,2,16,5","7,4,11,13,9,2,16,6","7,4,11,13,9,2,16,6";
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your desired output is? Should the entire entry provided be imported into a single character string?

Comment: Commas within quotes are treated as regular text; the one after KHTML is not within quotes (because that line has mismatched quotes).

Comment: So if i understand that correctly, the entire problem boils down to: Win64;" <- this misplaced quote. Is there any way to get rid of that for a large number of files? Would you encourage me to import the csv as a txt and then remove the quote with a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, you could use `readLines()` to read it without processing, remove the bad quote, then read it a second time after fixing it up.  I'll put the details in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the line you showed has mismatched quotes.  From the comments, it appears that the quote in `Win64;"` is not supposed to end the field, which is supposed to continue to `Safari/537.36"`.

Fixing this will need three steps:  read the file without interpreting fields, clean up the bad strings, then read it again as a CSV.  For example, if your file is called `data.csv`, you could do it like this:

```
lines <- readLines("data.csv")
cleaned <- sub('Win64;"', 'Win64;', lines)
data <- read.csv(textConnection(cleaned))
```

I don't know if the line to clean it will work in general:  you'll need to find out where those spurious quotes are, and work out a pattern to match and remove them.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the tools to solve the problem! I removed the '"' which does not appear to be in every single line... Still i cannot even import one "cleaned" line. I am specifying the seperator as ","but i just keeps getting ignored. 

`data <- read.csv(textConnection(cleaned[1:2]),sep = ",",header = F,skip = 1) (this is supposed to ensure that i am running my trial with only one line.) 

data[1,1] %>% writeClipboard() (If this matters this is how i extracted the one line)`

I edited my post to show one entire line. Could you kindly check if you spot the problem? Thank you!